# PowerShell hash-table return values

Tags: function, powershell, hashtable, return-value

I have a simple script to return values from a hash table:

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$Name
)

function getvalues ($Name) {

    $nameList= @{"CFT"=@{"name1"="text1"; "name2"="text2"}}

    #return $nameList[$Name]
    return ,$nameList
}

$Values = getvalues($Name)

    Write-Debug "DEBUG: Name1     = "$Values["name1"]
    Write-Debug "DEBUG: Name2     = "$Values["name2"]
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Write-Debug : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.
At C:\MSFT\add-test.ps1:21 char:2
+     write-Debug "DEBUG: Name1     = "$Values["name1"]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-Debug], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteDebugCommand

Write-Debug : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.
At C:\MSFT\add-test.ps1:22 char:2
+     write-Debug "DEBUG: Name2     = "$Values["name2"]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-Debug], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteDebugCommand
```

Comment: You should edit your question to fix the code formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're terminating your strings and then using the `$Values` lookup. Either use a `+` or embed it into the string, or use the `-f` operator:

```
write-Debug ("DEBUG: Name1   = " + $Values["name1"])
write-Debug "DEBUG: Name2   = $($Values["name2"])"
write-Debug ("DEBUG: Name3   = {0}" -f $Values["name3"])
```

Note forms 1 and 3 need parentheses `( )`.

Regarding your comment that there are no more errors and no output:

Are you sure your debug preference is set such that you can see the output? The point of `Write-Debug` and `Write-Verbose` is that you only see the output when the preference is set as such (and you shouldn't add `DEBUG:` in your string, it will be added for you). I suspect `Write-Verbose` is more appropriate for what you're doing.

To test quickly whether it will work, you can actually add `-Debug` or `-Verbose` as appropriate.

So for example:

```
Write-Verbose "Name2   = $($Values["name2"])" -Verbose
```

Comment: Write-Debug : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+'.
At C:\MSFT\add-test.ps1:21 char:2
+     write-Debug "DEBUG: Name1     = " + $Values["name1"]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-Debug], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteDebugCommand

Comment: Enclosing it in brackets might be the way to go here then. `write-Debug ("DEBUG: Name1   = " + $Values["name1"])` Odd that it didnt work.

Comment: with brackets in write-debug, I do not get any output ..but no error

Comment: The parentheses are needed for some of those, I've edited the question. If you're getting an error with those, is it a different error?

Comment: @Brian, I took a different approach:$Values    = getvalues($Name)

$name1 = $Values["name1"]
$name2 = $Values["name2"]
$name3 = $values["name3"]

 #write-Verbose ("Name1  = " + $Values["name1"])
 #write-Verbose "Name2  = $($Values["name2"])"
    #write-Verbose ("Name3   = {0}" -f $Values["name3"])

Write-Verbose ("Name1 = ") $name1
Write-Verbose ("Name2 = ") $name2
Write-Verbose ("Name3 = ") $name3

Comment: I get an error like the previous one ..can you please help!

Comment: @SBC it looks like you're making the exact same mistake; you're not doing anything to concatenate your strings.